# android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar was not found

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-toolbar, android-appcompat, androidx

The build.gradle file at app level is given below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.sscmessenger"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner 
"androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   //noinspection GradleCompatible
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-rc01'
   implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.2.2'
   implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.0.0'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'


   }
```

> Blockquote

Comment: post your XML aswell

Comment: Post also your layout but also your build.gradle file

Comment: Post your Build.Gradle Files.

Answer (score 0):

The class `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` can be found in the appcompat library.

Pay attention because

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
```

**doesn't exist.**
The [**28.0.0**](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) is the last version of support libraries.

Change your dependencies:

```
   implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
   //...
```

Better [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) your project to **androidx**.